# start rcp application from another rcp application

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an rcp eclipse application and from that application, using a context menu action I want to start a new rcp application . 
How do I do that ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you have two options.

Either you create a dependency between the two RCPs and when the user clicks the menu, just instantiate the second RCPs main class.

Or you could execute the second RCP as an external command. That means you will have to know where it is installed.

Comment: What do you mean the "the second RCPs main class" ? The org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication implementation? That seems not that simple to start - as it's called back from the platform which provides the IApplicationContext

Comment: Just _instantiate the second RCPs main class_ won't work. Unfortunately, the workbench (RCP) uses singletons and you would at least have to start a separate OSGi/Equinox container to isolate these. But possibly running two workbenches in a single VM isn't possible at all.